# getting insert queries from pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am using pgAdmin 4 and am looking to download query results as `INSERT` statements rather than as a CSV (the only option I can find). I am used to doing this with MySQL Workbench, but maybe I have been spoiled over there?

Is it possible in pgAdmin 4 to download query results as `INSERT` statements?

Comment: @dezso New to Postgres; used to MySQL. And I can't use the `COPY TO` a csv file and then `COPY FROM` a csv file solution I've found elsewhere because I can't write files on the database server I'm working with.

Comment: You might use either pgAdmin 4 to export/import the CSVs for you, or (in my opinion better) use `\copy` from `psql`.  The latter gives you the same functionality as the native `COPY`, but it writes/reads to/from the machine where the client is running.

Comment: @dezso I have 2 Postgres database servers. One has data in it and I can access it with pgAdmin 4. I want to move the data to the other one where I have only command line `psql` access and no text editor to write a csv file with. This is why copy doesn't seem to be the write path to go down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need this for moving data among databases, as you indicate in your comments, I'd suggest using `psql` and its `\copy` command.

This will definitely work, as it writes the files onto the local machine (the one the *client* is running on, eg. your laptop), and if you can connect using pgAdmin 4, you can also connect using `psql`.

The process would look like

```
psql -h dbhost -U whatever -d yourdb
psql> \copy table_name TO ~/table_name.csv WITH (FORMAT csv)
psql> \q

psql -h other-dbhost -U whatever -d your_other_db
psql> \copy other_table FROM ~/table_name.csv WITH (FORMAT csv)
```

The file location syntax assumes you are on Linux.